Permutation Multiplier for Marginal Likelihood
In the famous paper Scalable Marginal Likelihood Estimation for Model Selection in Deep Learning by Immer et al., Immer uses an approximate Laplace approximation for estimating the marginal log likelihood which is used for model selection over different neural network model architectures and sizes, following the spirit of A Practical Bayesian Framework for Backpropagation Networks by MacKay. However, one notable difference is that MacKay applies a permutation multiplier, as he correctly states that:

And if the network has a symmetry under permutation of its parameters, then we know that $M(w)$ [(the log posterior)] must share that symmetry, so that every single minimum belongs to a family of symmetric minima of $M$. For example, if there are $H$ hidden units in a single layer then each nondegenerate minimum is in a family of size
$g = H! 2^H$.

The question is - why does Immer exclude this permutation factor? I would think it matters especially when comparing models with different architectures and sizes?
